# Incremental Load from MySQL to MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I've tried different approaches for incremental load from MySQL to MS SQL Server. But found below approach optimal:

1. Get max(UpdateDate) from Destination table and read all the records having UpdateDate > max(UpdateDate) of destination table. (Execute SQL task to get max date from destination table. Storing in a variable)
2. Load these rows into temp table.
3. Lookup this temp table with destination table to find new and changed records.
4. Upsert the destination table.

But I am facing issues in this approach. The SSIS package failing with below error:

> "[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The
>   PrimeOutput method on ADO NET Source returned error code 0xC02090F5.
>   The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called
>   PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
>   component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure."

I removed lookup transformation and loaded data directly into the destination table and it worked fine but it inserted all the records from source table. It should have inserted records for which UpdateDate > max(UpdateDate) of destination table.

Please suggest.

Thank you!

Comment: The error that you have listed isn't the exact one. There may be few more errors. Could you list them as well?

Comment: It says "The ADO Net Source was unable to process data. Fatal Error encountered during data read"

Comment: This error points to the 'ADO.Net Source' component. Could you have a look at the parameters being sent to the source if the SQL is valid and is getting executed without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a Lookup in SSIS, load your step 2 data into a permanent staging table on the destination server.   Then steps 3 & 4 will be performed in a stored procedure rather than a dataflow.  It will be faster and less error-prone.